# Procedimiento almacenado no me muestra todos los valores que debería en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure, cursor

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado cuya finalidad es obtener la lista de los alumnos con la nota introducida como parámetro de entrada, pero sólo si es superior a la media.
El código es el siguiente:

```
use iesalandalus2;
DELIMITER //
create procedure obmedia1 (IN medianota float)
    begin
        declare notamedtotal float;
        declare listaalumnos varchar (250);
        set notamedtotal = (select avg(nota) from alumno);
        if (medianota > notamedtotal)
            then
                begin
                    declare control int default false;
                    declare cursornombreal cursor for select Nombre from alumno where nota > medianota;
                    declare continue handler for not found set control = true;
                    open cursornombreal;
                    bucle:loop
                        fetch cursornombreal into listaalumnos;
                        if control
                            then
                                begin
                                leave bucle;
                            end;
                        end if;
                    end loop;
                    select listaalumnos;
                    close cursornombreal;
                end;
        else
            begin
                select 'La nota introducida es inferior';
            end;
        end if;
    end;
```

El problema, es que solamente me saca el nombre de un alumno. ¿Debería de concatenar los nombres de alguna forma?

EDITO: Aquí está la tabla de la que quiero sacar la info:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/djrnU.jpg

Comment: Podrías añadir un ejemplo de las tablas con algunos datos de muestra, así te podemos ayudar más facíl.

Comment: Si ahora edito con una imagen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que `fetch` elimina el contenido de la variable para introducir un nuevo valor.

Cada vez que haces `fetch`. El nombre del alumno anterior es borrado, por lo que solo contendrá al final del procedimiento, el nombre del último alumno.

Lo que debes hacer es crear una tabla temporal `alumnos_tmp` con un campo nombre de tipo `VARCHAR` e ir insertando nombres de alumnos ahí.

Al final del procedure haces `SELECT * FROM alumnos_tmp`

El código sería algo así (He borrado algunos, begin/end innecesarios):

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure obmedia1 (IN medianota float)
    begin
        declare notamedtotal float;
        declare listaalumnos varchar (250);
        declare control int default false;
        declare cursornombreal cursor for select Nombre from alumno where nota > medianota;
        declare continue handler for not found set control = true;
        set notamedtotal = (select avg(nota) from alumno);
        if (medianota > notamedtotal) then
                    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE alumno_tmp ( nombre VARCHAR(50) );
                    open cursornombreal;
                    bucle:loop
                        fetch cursornombreal into listaalumnos;
                        insert into alumno_tmp (nombre) VALUES (listaalumnos);
                        if control then
                            leave bucle;
                        end if;
                    end loop;
                    select * from alumno_tmp;
                    close cursornombreal;
         end if;
    end//
```

Comment: Vale, entonces el fetch no es a la variable que creo, sino que  debe ser fetch into  tabla?

Comment: No, lo metes en la variable e insertas ese texto en la db. Vuelve a mirar la respuesta, la he editado